# Binding custom class inside ngClass in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-custom-component

I am trying to bind a class name inside Angular ngClass so that the user will be able to set any class name he  likes to the element.

I have the following in my js file and would like to assign this class name to the div element if this.customClass is set.

```
this.customClass= "list-custom-class";
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" [ngClass]="'{{customClass}}'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row {{customClass}}"></div>
```

No need of using **ngClass**.

Answer (score 0):

To bind class

```
<div class="row" [ngClass]="customClass"></div>
```

please check the below

https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 0):

You can't use string interpolation in ngClass.Please use below it may help.

```
[ngClass]="[customClass]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use it as class using string interpolation. Need not use ngClass to bind dynamic class through a variable.ngClass can be used in situations where you want to add class based on some conditions etc.,[image: Here is the output]

```
<span class="align-middle {{sub.sub2_sec_class}}" 
      [ngClass]="sub.isCurrent?'tab-head-icon-selected':'tab-head-icon'"> 
      {{sub.iconName}}
</span>
```

Here 'sub.sub2_sec_class' is a variable which dynamically populated for every ngFor loop iteration